# Add column average in output MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, average

I want to add a column of AVG in a existing output. First I calculate the usage of electricity and gas with a INNER JOIN. But now I want to add the AVG of "Day hour" to the output.

**Table columns**

```
Id, Datum, Tijd, consumed_rate1, consumed_rate2, gas
```

When I want output of last 24 records with usage of consumed_rate1, consumed_rate2 and gas, I use this query:

```
SELECT
    A.Datum AS Datum,
    A.Tijd AS Tijd,
    A.Daguur AS Daguur,
    A.Aantal AS Aantal,
    A.Consumed_rate1 + A.Consumed_rate2 AS Elektra,
    (A.Consumed_rate1 + A.Consumed_rate2 - B.Consumed_rate1 - B.Consumed_rate2) AS 'Elektra verbruikt',
    A.gas AS Gas, (A.gas - B.gas) AS 'Gas verbruikt' 
FROM smartmeter A 
INNER JOIN smartmeter B ON B.id = (A.id-1) 
ORDER BY A.Id DESC   
LIMIT 24
```

Now I want to add a column with AVG of usage from consumed_rate1 + consumed_rate2 and gas. I think I must work with LEFT JOINs, but I don’t know how. Is there any body that would help me with that?

Comment: Could you qrite it in pseudo code?I dont get `consumed_rate1 + consumed_rate2 and gas`.What do you mean and gas?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(Elektra), AVG(Gas)
FROM(
    SELECT
        A.Datum AS Datum,
        A.Tijd AS Tijd,
        A.Daguur AS Daguur,
        A.Aantal AS Aantal,
        A.Consumed_rate1 + A.Consumed_rate2 AS Elektra,
        (A.Consumed_rate1 + A.Consumed_rate2 - B.Consumed_rate1 - B.Consumed_rate2) AS 'Elektra verbruikt',
        A.gas AS Gas, (A.gas - B.gas) AS 'Gas verbruikt',
    FROM smartmeter A 
    INNER JOIN smartmeter B ON B.id = (A.id-1) 
    ORDER BY A.Id DESC   
    LIMIT 24
) as a
```